# How to use jssor carousel to build client carousal

Tags: jssor

Hi i'm trying to use jssor carousel to build client carousel and it's good but i need the carousel not stop at all between slides animation i set the AutoPlayInterval to 0 but it still stop for a littel between slides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set $SlideEasing option as follows,

```
var options = {
    ...
    $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$Linear,
    ...
};
```